SQL get rows where sum of col value is bigger than X
I have a table like this:



id
date
capacity
depot
reserved
order_id




1
2024-04-29
69
1
0
0


2
2024-04-29
49
1
0
0


3
2024-04-29
69
1
0
0


4
2024-04-29
69
1
0
0



Now I want to get only row where the sum of "capacity" is nearly to 100 - so my output should be



id
date
capacity
depot
reserved
order_id




1
2024-04-29
69
1
0
0


2
2024-04-29
49
1
0
0



Could you help me find the correct SQL statement?
I tried already to sum the capacity and group it by id with having sum >= 100 but I still get no results

What do you mean with "is nearly to 100"?

So, if I understand correct, you want to fetch a pair of rows whose sum of capacity is closest to 100? Since 69 + 49 are closer to 100 than 69 + 69, you would like to show those two rows? If this is correct so far, what do you want to do if further combinations of rows appear having the same sum? What if you need more than two rows to get a sum >= 100? Why do you want the rows with id 1 and 2 in your example, not 2 and 4? Please explain all possible cases and tell us what to do in those cases.

Your the sum of "capacity" is nearly to 100 is a linear cutting problem in practice. Of course, it can be solved on SQL, but I do not recommend you to realize this - the solution may hang your server even on a small rowset (~1000 rows).

A sample.
Caution! Do not reproduce on large datasets, this may hang your database server!
-- Create a table with the sample data - 10 rows with random values.

CREATE TABLE test (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  val INT
)
WITH RECURSIVE cte (num) AS (
  SELECT 1 
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT num + 1 FROM cte LIMIT 10
)
SELECT NULL id, 10 + RAND() * 50 val FROM cte;
SELECT * FROM test;




id
val




1
18


2
55


3
13


4
39


5
44


6
45


7
32


8
15


9
18


10
35



-- The task is to find a combination 
-- where the SUM of `val` values is close but not exceed the limit.

SET @limit = 100;

The solution. In practice we need the closest combination only, so LIMIT 1 should be added to the query. I have not added it, but the rows numbering is added instead. This allows you to understand the amount of investigated combinations and, hence, the size of temporary buffer needed.
WITH RECURSIVE
cte1 (id, val, rn) AS (
  SELECT id, val, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY val DESC, id ASC)
  FROM test
  ),
cte2 (id, val, rn, path, vals, total) AS (
  SELECT id, val, rn,
         CAST(id AS CHAR(65535)),
         CAST(val AS CHAR(65535)),
         val
  FROM cte1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT cte1.id, cte1.val, cte1.rn, 
         CONCAT_WS(',', cte2.path, cte1.id), 
         CONCAT_WS(',', cte2.vals, cte1.val), 
         cte2.total + cte1.val
  FROM cte2
  JOIN cte1 ON cte1.rn > cte2.rn
  WHERE cte2.total + cte1.val <= @limit
  )
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY total DESC, path ASC) rn,
       path, vals, total
FROM cte2 
ORDER BY total DESC, path ASC /* LIMIT 1 */ ;




rn
path
vals
total




1
10,7,1,8
35,32,18,15
100


2
10,7,9,8
35,32,18,15
100


3
2,6
55,45
100


4
2,7,3
55,32,13
100


5
10,1,9,8,3
35,18,18,15,13
99


6
2,5
55,44
99


7
4,7,8,3
39,32,15,13
99


8
6,4,8
45,39,15
99


9
10,7,1,3
35,32,18,13
98


10
10,7,9,3
35,32,18,13
98


11
5,4,8
44,39,15
98


12
6,10,1
45,35,18
98


13
6,10,9
45,35,18
98


14
5,10,1
44,35,18
97


15
5,10,9
44,35,18
97


16
6,4,3
45,39,13
97


17
5,4,3
44,39,13
96


18
6,1,9,8
45,18,18,15
96


19
7,1,9,8,3
32,18,18,15,13
96


20
10,7,8,3
35,32,15,13
95


21
5,1,9,8
44,18,18,15
95


22
6,10,8
45,35,15
95


23
6,7,1
45,32,18
95


24
6,7,9
45,32,18
95


25
2,4
55,39
94


26
5,10,8
44,35,15
94


27
5,7,1
44,32,18
94


28
5,7,9
44,32,18
94


29
6,1,9,3
45,18,18,13
94


30
5,1,9,3
44,18,18,13
93


31
6,10,3
45,35,13
93


32
4,10,1
39,35,18
92


33
4,10,9
39,35,18
92


34
5,10,3
44,35,13
92


35
6,7,8
45,32,15
92


36
2,1,9
55,18,18
91


37
5,7,8
44,32,15
91


38
6,1,8,3
45,18,15,13
91


39
6,9,8,3
45,18,15,13
91


40
2,10
55,35
90


41
4,1,9,8
39,18,18,15
90


42
5,1,8,3
44,18,15,13
90


43
5,9,8,3
44,18,15,13
90


44
6,7,3
45,32,13
90


45
4,10,8
39,35,15
89


46
4,7,1
39,32,18
89


47
4,7,9
39,32,18
89


48
5,7,3
44,32,13
89


49
6,5
45,44
89


50
2,1,8
55,18,15
88


51
2,9,8
55,18,15
88


52
4,1,9,3
39,18,18,13
88


53
2,7
55,32
87


54
4,10,3
39,35,13
87


55
10,1,9,8
35,18,18,15
86


56
2,1,3
55,18,13
86


57
2,9,3
55,18,13
86


58
4,7,8
39,32,15
86


59
10,7,1
35,32,18
85


60
10,7,9
35,32,18
85


61
4,1,8,3
39,18,15,13
85


62
4,9,8,3
39,18,15,13
85


63
10,1,9,3
35,18,18,13
84


64
4,7,3
39,32,13
84


65
6,4
45,39
84


66
2,8,3
55,15,13
83


67
5,4
44,39
83


68
7,1,9,8
32,18,18,15
83


69
10,7,8
35,32,15
82


70
10,1,8,3
35,18,15,13
81


71
10,9,8,3
35,18,15,13
81


72
6,1,9
45,18,18
81


73
7,1,9,3
32,18,18,13
81


74
10,7,3
35,32,13
80


75
5,1,9
44,18,18
80


76
6,10
45,35
80


77
5,10
44,35
79


78
6,1,8
45,18,15
78


79
6,9,8
45,18,15
78


80
7,1,8,3
32,18,15,13
78


81
7,9,8,3
32,18,15,13
78


82
5,1,8
44,18,15
77


83
5,9,8
44,18,15
77


84
6,7
45,32
77


85
5,7
44,32
76


86
6,1,3
45,18,13
76


87
6,9,3
45,18,13
76


88
4,1,9
39,18,18
75


89
5,1,3
44,18,13
75


90
5,9,3
44,18,13
75


91
4,10
39,35
74


92
2,1
55,18
73


93
2,9
55,18
73


94
6,8,3
45,15,13
73


95
4,1,8
39,18,15
72


96
4,9,8
39,18,15
72


97
5,8,3
44,15,13
72


98
10,1,9
35,18,18
71


99
4,7
39,32
71


100
2,8
55,15
70


101
4,1,3
39,18,13
70


102
4,9,3
39,18,13
70


103
10,1,8
35,18,15
68


104
10,9,8
35,18,15
68


105
2,3
55,13
68


106
7,1,9
32,18,18
68


107
10,7
35,32
67


108
4,8,3
39,15,13
67


109
10,1,3
35,18,13
66


110
10,9,3
35,18,13
66


111
7,1,8
32,18,15
65


112
7,9,8
32,18,15
65


113
1,9,8,3
18,18,15,13
64


114
10,8,3
35,15,13
63


115
6,1
45,18
63


116
6,9
45,18
63


117
7,1,3
32,18,13
63


118
7,9,3
32,18,13
63


119
5,1
44,18
62


120
5,9
44,18
62


121
6,8
45,15
60


122
7,8,3
32,15,13
60


123
5,8
44,15
59


124
6,3
45,13
58


125
4,1
39,18
57


126
4,9
39,18
57


127
5,3
44,13
57


128
2
55
55


129
4,8
39,15
54


130
10,1
35,18
53


131
10,9
35,18
53


132
4,3
39,13
52


133
1,9,8
18,18,15
51


134
10,8
35,15
50


135
7,1
32,18
50


136
7,9
32,18
50


137
1,9,3
18,18,13
49


138
10,3
35,13
48


139
7,8
32,15
47


140
1,8,3
18,15,13
46


141
9,8,3
18,15,13
46


142
6
45
45


143
7,3
32,13
45


144
5
44
44


145
4
39
39


146
1,9
18,18
36


147
10
35
35


148
1,8
18,15
33


149
9,8
18,15
33


150
7
32
32


151
1,3
18,13
31


152
9,3
18,13
31


153
8,3
15,13
28


154
1
18
18


155
9
18
18


156
8
15
15


157
3
13
13



fiddle

If you'd find the closest combination without the restriction "not exceed" then you'd edit the query slightly:
WITH RECURSIVE
cte1 (id, val, rn) AS (
  SELECT id, val, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY val DESC, id ASC)
  FROM test
  ),
cte2 (id, val, rn, path, vals, total) AS (
  SELECT id, val, rn,
         CAST(id AS CHAR(65535)),
         CAST(val AS CHAR(65535)),
         val
  FROM cte1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT cte1.id, cte1.val, cte1.rn, 
         CONCAT_WS(',', cte2.path, cte1.id), 
         CONCAT_WS(',', cte2.vals, cte1.val), 
         cte2.total + cte1.val
  FROM cte2
  JOIN cte1 ON cte1.rn > cte2.rn
  WHERE cte2.total < @limit
  )
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ABS(@limit - total) ASC, path ASC) rn,
       path, vals, total
FROM cte2 
ORDER BY ABS(@limit - total) ASC, path ASC /* LIMIT 1 */;


See the linked fiddle, but I was able to get results for the test data you provided with the following:
create table test (
id int,
  date date, 
  capacity int, depot int,
  reserved tinyint(1),
  order_id int);
  

insert into test values (1, '2024-04-29', 69, 1, 0, 0), (2, '2024-04-29', 49, 1 ,0 ,0),
( 3, '2024-04-29', 69,1, 0, 0),
(4 ,'2024-04-29' ,69 , 1, 0 , 0);


Records: 4  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0


Here I'm assuming you want to sum by date, but if that's not the case you should be able to swap out the aggregation column easily:
select date, sum(capacity) as total from test group by date having total > 100;




date
total




2024-04-29
256



fiddle

You have misunderstood the question. You can hence delete this answer.
